# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un id a cada row?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, bootstrap, codeigniter

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, quiero agregarle un id a cada uno de los cuadros de mi tabla en este caso cada `row`, tengo mi tabla de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito agregarle un id a cada cuadrito que se encuentra con un guion `-`.  El id sera respecto a su posición, en este caso en Presentación seria `id = 1-2`, en Presentación (4ta posición) seria `id = 1,3` y así sucesivamente y cuando sea otro renglón cambiaría a  `id= 2-2` o `id= 2-3` y así respectivamente.

Utilizo codeigniter, bootstrap-tables, JSON, javascrit.

Para crear la tabla utilizo el siguiente código:

```
$('#ejemplo').bootstrapTable({
      url:'<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemplo/presentacion/datos',
      columns: [
        {field: 'mate',filter:{type:"input"}},
        {field: 'idMate',filter:{type:"input"}},
        {field: 'pres',filter:{type:"input"}}
      ],

      pagination: true,
      showFooter: true,
      showHeader: true,
      search: true,
      showExport:true,
      filter: true,
      method: 'post',
      showRefresh:true,

    });
```

El encabezado lo agrego directamente en htlm, al crear mi encabezado la Presentación se pone de manera dinamica dependiendo cuantas se traiga de mi base de datos.

```
<table id="materiales">
   <thead>
     <?php  
       $pres = explode(",",$presentacion);
         echo '<th>Materiales</th>';
         echo '<th></th>';
            for ($i=0; $i <count($pres) ; $i++) { 
              echo '<th>'.$pres[$i].'</th>';
            }                          
  ?>
</thead>
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a realizar eso en javascript.

Comment: Eso sin duda se puede lograr en el momento en que estas creando las filas y tus columnas. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para añadir el código que estas usando para crear la tabla, ya sea dinámico o estático?

Comment: listo @Kenny, espero me puedas ayudar!!!

Comment: Las celdas con - tienen alguna clase?? Y me imagino que la tabla ya está hecha, es decir la escribiste en el html, javascript no la crea??

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán agregué el código html de la tabla.

Comment: Encontre la documentación de bootstrap-tables (nunca habia escuchado de esta libreria) y al parecer hay una propiedad de la tabla que se llama "uniqueId" que asigna Id unicos a cada fila (no creo que a cada celda). Puedes verla aqui: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ Tambien encontre que hay otra forma de crear la tabla, que en vez de usar JavaScript (como ahora lo haces) puedes hacerlo directamente en el html, y en ese caso creo que talves si se podria un id unico para cada celda, este es el link http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues se podría hacer con algo así:

```js
var filas = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"), celdas;
 for (var i = 0; i < filas.length; i++){
  filas[i].firstElementChild.id = i+"-0";  //Sólo suponiendo que Materiales sea el primer td, de lo contrario
  celdas = filas[i].children;
  for (var j = 0; j < celdas.length; j++){
   let celda_actual = celdas[j];
   if(celda_actual.textContent == "-")//Sólo si llegasen a haber más celdas con contenido que no sea -
    celda_actual.id = i+"-"+j;
  }
 }
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>hola</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>hola</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>hola</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>hola</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sí, de acuerdo, pero hasta abajo comenta: "Alguien que me pueda ayudar a realizar eso en javascript.", por lo que entendí hacerlo en javascript, y no en la librería bootstrap-tables.js de javascript, por ello, @Soldier ¿Podrías aclarar si lo quieres en javascript puro o en la librería?

Comment: seria en javascript y bootstrap-tables utilizando los dos, ya que para mandar los datos (columnas le mando el json y el bootstrap-tables), ya solo seria que a cada `td` se le agregara un id respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias @Benjamin Guzman,  me funcionó perfecto, solo lo adapte un poco  para que funcionara con Bootstrap-tables. :)